# Fetch SYS_REFCURSOR into a table with unknown columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sys-refcursor

I have a procedure which returns a `SYS_REFCURSOR` as an `OUT` parameter. What I would like to do is call that procedure, and use that returned `SYS_REFCURSOR` in another procedure. In this second procedure, I would need to run a `GROUP BY` on the results, and return it in another `SYS_REFCURSOR`.

The problem I'm encountering is that I do not know the name or number of columns in advance.

Does anyone have any ideas for a solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Solution that you are asking is too big for SO (IMHO). You can start from here: http://www.oraclerecipes.com/dynamic-sql/get-columns-from-ref-cursor/. Also try to search other examples of using `DBMS_SQL` package.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 11g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can do this, but it requires some effort and for most cases it's just overkill.

The way is the next sequence of steps:

1. Create XMLTYPE from sys_refcursor
2. Parse sys_refcursor via dbms_sql, get information about columns
3. Create dynamic sql, which will be select from XMLTYPE via xpath, based on information from step 2

simple example, to illustrate the idea:

`select EMPNO, count(*) from
  xmltable(
   ‘/ROWSET/ROW’
   PASSING xmltype(CURSOR( SELECT E.EMPNO, E.ENAME, D.DNAME, D.DEPTNO FROM SCOTT.EMP E, SCOTT.DEPT D WHERE e.deptno=D.DEPTNO ))
   columns
   EMPNO  PATH ‘EMPNO’,
   ENAME PATH ‘ENAME’,
   DNAME PATH  ‘DNAME’ ,
   DEPTNO PATH ‘DEPTNO’
  )
group by EMPNO`

Comment: Yea, I thought it was possible with some creativity. Thanks!